# Вычислить градус поворота View элемента

Tags: java, android, геометрия

На заднем фоне View элемент напоминающий треугольник.
Синим показан элемент который нужно развернуть вдоль гипотенузы.
Подскажите, как можно вычислить значение для параметра `rotation` View элемента Android.

Ширина синего элемента math_parent.

Начал делать так:

```
 triangle.post(()->{
            double hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(triangle.getHeight(), 2) + Math.pow(triangle.getWidth(), 2));

            double angleA = Math.sin((double) triangle.getHeight() / (double) triangle.getWidth());
            double angleA_1 = Math.atan((double) triangle.getHeight() / (double) triangle.getWidth());
            double angleB = 180D - 90D - angleA;

            Log.d("myTag", "Гипотинуза " + hypotenuse + "\nWidth: " + triangle.getWidth() + "\nangleA: " + angleA + "\nangleB " + angleB);
        });
```

OUT:

> Гипотинуза 729.9315036357864
>
> Width: 720
>
> angleA: 0.16589613269341502
>
> angleA_1 0.16514867741462683
>
> angleB 89.83410386730658

Вроде вычисления выше правильные, но что делать дальше не соображу..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну видимо теперь нужно один из полученных углов использовать для параметра rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вы посчитали синус угла по формуле для тангенса угла
2. Угол и синус угла это разные вещи. Чтобы из тангенса получить угол нужен арктангенс.

Полагаю у вас начальное состояние примерно как на рисунке ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда:

```
double AngleA=Math.atan((double) triangle.getHeight() / (double) triangle.getWidth());
```

Обратите внимание на то, что сразу получен угол в радианах, который принимает на вход rotate.

Если нужно в градусах, то можно сделать так как подсказывают в комментарии

```
float rotate = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((double) triangle.getHeight() / (double) triangle.getWidth()));
view.setRotation(-rotate);
```

Comment: В доках метода упоминается 'degress' - это вроде в градусах, если по-русски. А 0,16 градуса почти не заметны. Пробуйте перевести в градусы `Math.toDegress()` и применить.

Comment: @woesss автором получен не угол, а синус угла по формуле для тангенса. Смотрите внимательно: есть угол, а есть его тангенс и это разные вещи. Если нужно в градусах то из радиан легко перевести, согласен.

Comment: Добавьте в ответ вот такое и я его приму как правильный ответ. float rotate = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((double) triangle.getHeight() / (double) triangle.getWidth()));
view.setRotation(-rotate);